# React Typescript element types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What's the type of the following statement in React?

```
let element = <div>Blah blah</div>
```

I thought I could use `element: HTMLElement` but when I do, I get `Property 'accessKey' is missing in type 'Element'`.

What about another imported component?

```
import Row from './partials/Row';
let row = <Row cols={cols} />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type for the div jsx element is [`HTMLFactory<HTMLDivElement>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/index.d.ts#L2254).

The reference you have isn't for an actual dom element in the browser but for a react element which represent such an element which might not be rendered yet.

The html properties should be accessed through the props:

```
let element = <div>Blah blah</div>
console.log(element.props.accessKey);
```

If you'd like to get the dom element you can use the [ref attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> When the ref attribute is used on an HTML element, the ref callback
>   receives the underlying DOM element as its argument

So:

```
let divElement: HTMLDivElement;
let element = <div ref={ (el) => { divElement = el; console.log(el); } }>Blah blah</div>
```

In the case of the imported `Row`, again, you have a reference to a react element which has a dom representation.
Which properties or methods it has depends on the class itself.

Comment: Well, `HTMLDivElement` now says property `align` is missing. I tried to change to span, but I get `addEventListener` is missing.

Comment: Are you sure? For me `divElement.align` exist. It's part of the [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L8223)